# VirtualBox: Could not get storage format of the medium

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a VMWare Ubuntu 64-bit virtual machine and when I get to the hard disk step, I choose to use an existing virtual disk file and add my `.vmdk` file.  Note that it doesn't ask for my `.vmx` file which I also have.  Upon adding it, I get the following error message:

> Failed to open the disk image file
>   /home/username/Desktop/vmfolder/VirtualDisk-s001.vmdk.

With the following details:

> Could not get the storage format of the medium
>   '/home/username/Desktop/someFolder/vmfolder/VirtualDisk-s001.vmdk' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
>
> Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
>   Component: MediumWrap
>   Interface: IMedium {ad47ad09-787b-44ab-b343-a082a3f2dfb1}
>   Callee:  IVirtualBox {d0a0163f-e254-4e5b-a1f2-011cf991c38d}
>   Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)